# cant set DropdownList name with variable in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to set `dropdown List` name with `viewbag` value  like belowe , but is returns `compile error`

```
   @{ 
    var ControlName = ViewBag.controlname;
}

@Html.DropDownList(ControlName , Model,"please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

when change it to this , its work fine :

```
@Html.DropDownList("typename", Model, "please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: `ViewBag` is `dynamic` - you need to cast it to a `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cast it to string first

```
@{
    var ControlName = (string)ViewBag.controlname;
}

@Html.DropDownList(ControlName , Model,"please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The `ViewBag` is a dynamic object. So you have to explicitly cast's it's properties, when you are about to use them.

For further info, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx).